# CSS How to hide text after a span

Tags: html, css, hidden

The following is some code from a template I am developing for Joomla.  The code below is the output generated.

Is it possible to hide text within an a tag after a closing span using css?  For example how do I get the words Print, Email and Edit to be hidden?

```
<ul class="icons">
  <li class="print-icon">
    <a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;"><span class="icon-print"></span>Print</a>
  </li>
  <li class="email-icon">
    <a href="#email"><span class="icon-envelope"></span>Email</a>
  </li>
  <li class="edit-icon">
    <a href="#edit"><span class="icon-edit"></span>Edit</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you not change the html that is outputted? Is there a reason why you have to change it with CSS?

Comment: Try the pseudo-element selector, e.g. `.icon-print::after{content:none;}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to try setting your anchor tags to inline block and giving them the width of your icon and then setting overflow to hidden:

```
.edit-icon a, .email-icon a, .print-icon a { display: inline-block; width: 16px; overflow: hidden; }
```

Here's a little [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrettEast/x55utqye/)

Comment: Neat idea, I will try of that :)

Comment: This is the better solution as it targets the specific icons :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't actually select text nodes directly, one work-around would be to set the `font-size` of the parent element to `0`. Then reset the `font-size` for those desired `span` elements. In doing so, only the `span` elements should appear, and the adjacent text nodes *should* effectively be hidden.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/at0scvfz/)

```css
.icons li a {
    font-size: 0;
}
.icons li a span {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul class="icons">
  <li class="print-icon">
    <a href="#" onclick="window.print();return false;"><span class="fa fa-print"></span>Print</a>
  </li>
  <li class="email-icon">
    <a href="#email"><span class="fa fa-envelope"></span>Email</a>
  </li>
  <li class="edit-icon">
    <a href="#edit"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span>Edit</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool idea, I will try the one above and if that is not working will try your suggested solution :)

Answer (score -1):

You can just leave the words out of the html.

```
<a href="#email"><span class="icon-envelope"></span>Email</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="#email"><span class="icon-envelope"></span></a>
```

Comment: Yes I can do that by editing a core file in Joomla but that is not a good idea as a future update will put them back in.

The output above is what I have to work with.

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Joomla as I am with other CMS. In wordpress you can just replace the core file from the theme by creating a child theme that has the same file. Then it won't be over-written during updates. Is that an option in Joomla?